# Is it a good practice if using Object when a method can accept more than one type of object?

Tags: java, design, interfaces, producer-consumer

```
public class TaskA implements Runnable {
....
}
public class TaskB implements Runnable {
....
}
```

I have two runnable class as TaskA, TaskB. I want to have a TaskManager to run these two tasks and have possibility to add more task in the future. So I have the TaskManager as following:

```
public class TaskManager {
    private ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool;
    private Object task;

    public TaskManager(TaskA task) {
        this.task = task;
    }
    public TaskManager(TaskB task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public void startThreadPool() {
        threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(...);
        threadPool.execute((Runnable) task);
    }
}
```

I would like to know whether it is a good practice? If not, anyone have any suggestion? should we use consumer or so to implement this one?

Comment: `private Runnable task;`... and I'm not sure what your `TaskManager` offers above and beyond what the `ThreadPoolExecutor` offers anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since it seems you only use task as a `Runnable` internally, use Runnable instead of Object.  Change your third line to:

`private final Runnable task;`

Simple, saves you a cast later.  And I'd *consider* renaming it from "task" to "runnable" for clarity, if that makes more sense.

Comment: Changing it to a `Runnable`, yes. Renaming it?... Very debatable.

Comment: Valid point, edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:**

Use just one constructor that accepts a `Runnable` and a member of type `Runnable`.

**Long answer:**

If you really, **really need to have two difrerent constructors**, one that receives a `TaskA` and one that receives a `TaskB`, (one possible reason is that `TaskManager` calls methods that are particular to `TaskA` or `TaskB`) then you have two options:

1. Have two members, `private TaskA taskA` and `private TaskB taskB`
2. Have just one member `private Runnable task`, since `Runnable` is the common ancestor of `TaskA` and `TaskB`

In the other hand, **if you don't really need a constructor for each type** of task, you can have just one constructor `public TaskManager(Runnable task)` and only one member of type `Runnable` like in option 2 previously stated.

It all dependends of whether or not you will need to call methods that are particular to `TaskA` or `TaskB`. If `TaskManager` only really cares about the `Runnable` contract then there's no need for two constructors, let alone having to cast an `Object` to a `Runnable` to run it.

Lastly, if `TaskManager` really needs something from the tasks beside the `Runnable` functionality, then create a `RunnableTask` like this:

```
public interface RunnableTask extends Runnable {
    public int getThis();
    public int getThat();
}

public class TaskA implements RunnableTask { ... }
public class TaskB implements RunnableTask { ... }

public class TaskManager {
    ...
    private RunnableTask task;

    public TaskManager(RunnableTask task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public void startThreadPool() {
        threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(...);
        threadPool.execute(task);
        // do somewthing with task.getThis();
        // do somewthing with task.getThat();
    }
    ...
}
```